# How do I solve Untrusted's levels?

Tags: untrusted

I am playing [*Untrusted*](https://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/) (JavaScript adventure game) and I am stuck at a particular level. How do I solve that?

Even after I solved a level, I am curious to know if there are better approaches. Is there a compilation, or a walk-through of  optimal ways to solve *Untrusted*'s levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the successful solutions are [publicly available](https://gist.github.com/Untrusted-Game), I spend some time analyzing them and compiled a list of all the (sensible) approaches to solve each level, that I could find.

https://gist.github.com/mhasdf/40363e0c1c807663d8c6ccb797aa94fa

---

## Solutions for the Untrusted Game

untrusted game: https://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/

### Level 1

cellBlockA.js
01_cellBlockA.jsx

```
// remove all code
```

### Level 2

theLongWayOut.js
02_theLongWayOut.jsx

```
/*
*/
```

### Level 3

validationEngaged.js
03_validationEngaged.jsx

```
    for (y = 10; y <= map.getHeight() - 3; y++) {
        map.placeObject(0, y, 'block');  // change 5 to 0
        map.placeObject(map.getWidth() - 5, y, 'block');
    }

    for (x = 5; x <= map.getWidth() - 5; x++) {
        map.placeObject(x, 10, 'block');
        map.placeObject(x, map.getHeight() - 3, 'block');
    }
```

### Level 4

multiplicity.js
04_multiplicity.jsx

```
map.placeObject(40, 20, 'exit');
```

### Level 5

minesweeper.js
05_minesweeper.jsx

```
map.setSquareColor(x, y, '#000');
```

### Level 6

drones101.js
06_drones101.jsx

```
map.placeObject(20, 11, 'block');
map.placeObject(20, 12, 'block');
map.placeObject(21, 13, 'block');
map.placeObject(22, 12, 'block');
```

or

```
var i = 0;
map.defineObject('timebomb', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': 'C',
    'color': '#ff0',
    'behavior': function (me) {
        if (i === 10) {
            x = 37;
            y = 12;
            map.placeObject(x-1, y, 'block');
            map.placeObject(x+1, y, 'block');
            map.placeObject(x, y-1, 'block');
            map.placeObject(x, y+1, 'block');
        }
        i++;
    }
});
map.placeObject(34, 12, 'timebomb');
```

or with an idea from a later level

```
map.placeObject(1, 13, 'teleporter');
map.placeObject(45, 13, 'teleporter');
var t = map.getDynamicObjects();
t[1].setTarget(t[2]);
```

or with an idea from a later level

```
map.defineObject('turret', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '=',
    'color': 'yellow',
    'interval': 200,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        if ((me.i = (me.i ?? 0) + 1) < 10) {
            map.placeObject(me.getX() + 1, me.getY(), 'bullet');
        }
    }
});
map.defineObject('bullet', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '.',
    'color': 'yellow',
    'interval': 100,
    'projectile': true,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('right');
    }
});
map.placeObject(20, 12, 'turret');
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl6-solution.js%22)

### Level 7

colors.js
07_colors.jsx

```
var player = map.getPlayer();
var colors = {
    '#f00': '#ff0',
    '#ff0': '#0f0',
    '#0f0': '#f00'
};
player.setColor(colors[player.getColor()]);
```

or

```
var player = map.getPlayer();
if (player.i === undefined) player.i = 0;
var colors = ['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0'];
player.setColor(colors[player.i]);
player.i = (player.i + 1) % colors.length;
```

or

```
var player = map.getPlayer();
var colors = ['#0f0', '#f00', '#ff0'];
var i = player.i ?? 0;
map.startTimer(function () {
  player.setColor(colors[i++ % colors.length]);
}, 500);
```

or

```
var player = map.getPlayer();
if (player.getX() === 24 || player.getX() === 33) {
    player.setColor('#f00');
} else if (player.getX() === 27 || player.getX() === 36) {
    player.setColor('#ff0');
} else {
    player.setColor('#0f0');
}
```

Nice to remember:

```
map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {});
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl7-solution.js%22)

### Level 8

intoTheWoods.js
08_intoTheWoods.jsx

```
"generateForest"
```

### Level 9

fordingTheRiver.js
09_fordingTheRiver.jsx

```
map.defineObject('bridge', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '☰',
    'color': '#f77',
    'transport': true,
});
for (var y = 5; y < 15; y++) {
    map.placeObject(10, y, 'bridge');
}
```

or

```
map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {
    raftDirection = 'up';
});
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl9-solution.js%22)

### Level 10

ambush.js
10_ambush.jsx

```
///// attackDrone
if (me.canMove('up')) {
    me.move('up');
} else {
    me.move('left');
}
///// reinforcementDrone
me.move('up');
///// defenseDrone
if (me.canMove('up')) {
    me.move('up');
} else {
    me.move('right');
}
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl10-solution.js%22)

### Level 11

robot.js
11_robot.jsx

```
if (me.canMove('right')) {
    me.move('right');
} else {
    me.move('down');
}
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl11-solution.js%22)

### Level 12

robotNav.js
12_robotNav.jsx

```
if (me.getX() < 25) {
    if (me.canMove('down')) {
        me.move('down');
    } else {
        me.move('right');
    }
} else if (me.getX() < 30) {
    if (me.canMove('up')) {
        me.move('up');
    } else {
        me.move('right');
    }
} else {
    if (me.canMove('right')) {
        me.move('right');
    } else {
        me.move('down');
    }
}
```

Also, see Level 13 solutions.

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl12-solution.js%22)

### Level 13

robotMaze.js
13_robotMaze.jsx

```
var a = ['left', 'up', 'right', 'down'];
if (me.i === undefined) {
    me.i = 0;
    map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {
        me.i = (me.i + 1) % 4;
    });
}
me.move(a[me.i]);
```

or

```
map.setSquareColor(41, 22, '#770');
map.setSquareColor(42, 21, '#770');
map.setSquareColor(43, 22, '#770');
map.setSquareColor(42, 23, '#770');
if (player.atLocation(41, 22))
    me.move('left');
if (player.atLocation(42, 21))
    me.move('up');
if (player.atLocation(43, 22))
    me.move('right');
if (player.atLocation(42, 23))
    me.move('down');
```

or

```
if (me.i === undefined) {
    me.i = 1;
    map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {
        if (me.i++ % 2) {
            map.overrideKey('left', ()=>{ me.move('left'); });
            map.overrideKey('up', ()=>{ me.move('up'); });
            map.overrideKey('right', ()=>{ me.move('right'); });
            map.overrideKey('down', ()=>{ me.move('down'); });
        } else {
            map.overrideKey('left', null);
            map.overrideKey('up', null);
            map.overrideKey('right', null);
            map.overrideKey('down', null);
        }
    });
}
```

or

```
var a = {
    'left': ['down', 'up'],
    'up': ['left', 'right'],
    'right': ['up', 'down'],
    'down': ['right', 'left'],
};
if (me.i === undefined) me.i = 'up';
if (me.j === undefined) me.j = false;
if (me.j && me.canMove(a[me.i][0])) {
    me.i = a[me.i][0];
} else if (me.canMove(me.i) && !me.canMove(a[me.i][0])) {
    me.j = true;
} else if (!me.canMove(me.i)) {
    me.i = a[me.i][1];
}
me.move(me.i);
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl13-solution.js%22)

### Level 14

crispsContest.js
14_crispsContest.jsx

```
theAlgorithm
```

left (blue), greenKey, up, blueKey, center, right (red), blueKey, up, redKey, center, down, theAlgorithm, right, yellowKey, center, exit

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl14-solution.js%22)

### Level 15

exceptionalCrossing.js
15_exceptionalCrossing.jsx

```
a
```

or

```
'');}, 'onCollision':function () {//
```

### Level 16

lasers.js
16_lasers.jsx

```
// using canvas to draw the line
var ctx = map.getCanvasContext();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.stroke();
/////
map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {
    var player = map.getPlayer();
    player.i = ((player.i ?? -1) + 1) % colors.length;
    player.setColor(colors[player.i]);
});
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl16-solution.js%22)

### Level 17

pointers.js
17_pointers.jsx

```
if (i === teleportersAndTraps.length - 2) {
    var obj = map.getDynamicObjects();
    var a = obj[0];
    var b = obj[obj.length - 2];  // teleporter nearest to exit
    a.setTarget(b);
    var c = map.getCanvasContext();
    c.beginPath();
    c.strokeStyle = 'purple';
    c.lineWidth = 4;
    c.moveTo(map.getCanvasCoords(a).x, map.getCanvasCoords(a).y);
    c.lineTo(map.getCanvasCoords(b).x, map.getCanvasCoords(b).y);
    c.stroke();
}
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl17-solution.js%22)

### Level 18

superDrEvalBros.js
18_superDrEvalBros.jsx

```
}
function gravity() {
```

or

```
map.defineObject('bridge', {
    'symbol': '=',
    'color': '#dd0',
    'impassable': true
});
for (var x = 20; x < 30; x++) {
    map.placeObject(x, fl(h/2), 'bridge');
}
```

or

```
map.placeObject(19,11,'teleporter');
map.placeObject(30,11,'teleporter');
var d = map.getDynamicObjects();
d[0].setTarget(d[1]);
```

or

```
map.startTimer(function () {
    var x = player.getX();
    var y = player.getY();
    if (x < 35) {
        if (y > 1) {
            player.move('up');
        } else {
            player.move('right');
        }
    }
}, 25);
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl18-solution.js%22)

### Level 19

documentObjectMadness.js
19_documentObjectMadness.jsx

Bring the green highlight (deEval) to the red highlight (adversary)

- up = moveToParent
- down = moveToFirstChild
- left = moveToPreviousSibling
- right = moveToNextSibling

### Level 20

bossFight.js
20_bossFight.jsx

```
map.defineObject('missile', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '^',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('up');
    }
});
/// You need to make it to the other side for the phone :-(
var player = map.getPlayer()
player.setPhoneCallback(() => {
    map.placeObject(player.getX(), player.getY() -2, 'missile');
});
```

or

```
map.defineObject('missile', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '^',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('up');
    }
});
/// Shield
map.defineObject('shield', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '/',
    'color': 'purple',
    'impassable': true,
    'passableFor': ['missile']
});
for(var x = 2; x < 48; x++) {
    map.placeObject(x, 19, 'shield');
}
var player = map.getPlayer();
player.setPhoneCallback(() => {
    map.placeObject(player.getX(), player.getY() -2, 'missile');
});
```

or

```
map.defineObject('missile', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '^',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('up');
    }
});
/// Don't let the boss fire
Math.random = function () {
    return 1;
}
var player = map.getPlayer();
player.setPhoneCallback(() => {
    map.placeObject(player.getX(), player.getY() -2, 'missile');
});
```

or

```
map.defineObject('missile', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '^',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('up');
    }
});
/// Use left arrow key
map.overrideKey('left', function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < map.getWidth(); x++) {
        map.placeObject(x, 15, 'missile');
    }
});
```

or

```
map.defineObject('missle', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '>',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('right');
    }
});
map.defineObject('trigger', {
    'symbol': '+',
    'color': 'orange',
    'onCollision': function () {
        map.placeObject(0,5, 'missle');
        map.placeObject(0,6, 'missle');
    }
});
map.placeObject(0, 24, 'trigger');
```

or

```
map.defineObject('missle', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '>',
    'color': 'orange',
    'projectile': true,
    'interval': 100,
    'behavior': function (me) {
        me.move('right');
    }
});
Math.random = function () {
    map.placeObject(0, 5, 'missle');
    map.placeObject(0, 6, 'missle');
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
map.defineObject('trigger', {
    'symbol': '+',
    'color': 'orange',
    'onCollision': function () {
        map.getDynamicObjects().forEach( function (o) {
            /// Hit them with their own bullets
            map.placeObject(o.getX(), o.getY() - 1, 'bullet');
        });
    }
});
map.placeObject(0, 24, 'trigger');
```

or

```
/// Landing
map.getDynamicObjects().forEach(function (o) {
    o.direction = "down";
});
map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function () {
    for(var x = 2; x < 48; x++) {
        map.placeObject(x, 10, 'bullet');
    }
});
```

[Other Solutions](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%22untrusted-lvl20-solution.js%22)

### Level 21

21_endOfTheLine.jsx

Go to Menu, scripts/objects.js

Find this code and comment out the if condition

```
'exit' : {
    'symbol' : String.fromCharCode(0x2395), // ⎕
    'color': '#0ff',
    'onCollision': function (player) {
        if (!game.map.finalLevel) {
            game._callUnexposedMethod(function () {
                game._moveToNextLevel();
            });
        }
    }
},
```

### bonus / 01_inTheDesert.jsx

inTheDesert.js

No code changes needed. Don't move too far away from the E. The E deactivates the laser.

### bonus / 02_theEmptyRoom.jsx

theEmptyRoom.js

```
return {15:610,
16:987,
17:1597,
18:2584,
19:4181,
20:6765,
21:10946,
22:17711,
23:28657,
24:46368,
25:75025,
26:121393,
27:196418,
28:317811,
29:514229,
30:832040,
31:1346269,
32:2178309,
33:3524578,
34:5702887,
35:9227465,
36:14930352,
37:24157817,
38:39088169,
39:63245986,
40:102334155,
41:165580141,
42:267914296,
43:433494437,
44:701408733,
45:1134903170,
46:1836311903,
47:2971215073,
48:4807526976,
49:7778742049,
50:12586269025,
51:20365011074,
52:32951280099,
53:53316291173,
54:86267571272,
55:139583862445,
56:225851433717,
57:365435296162,
58:591286729879,
59:956722026041,
60:1548008755920,
61:2504730781961,
62:4052739537881,
63:6557470319842,
64:0x9a661ca20bb,
65:0xf9d297a859d,
66:27777890035288,
67:44945570212853,
68:72723460248141,
69:0x6b04f4c2fe42,
70:0xad2934c6d08f,
71:308061521170129,
72:498454011879264,
73:806515533049393,
74:0x4a2dce62b0d91,
75:0x780626e057bc2,
76:0xc233f54308953,
77:5527939700884757,
78:8944394323791464,
79:0x336a82d89c937c,
80:0x533163ef0321e4,
81:0x869be6c79fb560,
82:0xd9cd4ab6a2d740,
83:99194853094755490,
84:0x23a367c34e563e0,
85:0x39a9fadb327f080,
86:0x5d4d629e80d5480,
87:0x96f75d79b354500,
88:0xf444c0183429980,
89:0x18b3c1d91e77de00,
90:0x27f80ddaa1ba7800,
91:466004661037553e4,
92:0x68a3dd8e61ecd000,
93:0xa94fad42221f2800,
94:0x111f38ad0840c0000,
95:319404346349901e5,
96:5168070885485833e4,
97:8362114348984843e4,
98:0x755b0bdd8fa998000,
99:2189229958345552e5,
100:3542248481792619e5}[input];
```

### bonus / 03_theCollapsingRoom.jsx

theCollapsingRoom.js

```
half_width = 5;
```

### bonus / 04_theGuard.jsx

theGuard.js

```
map.placeObject(26, 12, 'block');
map.placeObject(28, 12, 'block');
map.placeObject(27, 13, 'block');
```

or

```
/// Use eyes to block guard
map.placeObject(40, 20, 'eye');
```

### bonus / 05_theCorridor.jsx

```
function trap_behaviour (me, left, right) {}
```

### bonus / AB_1_ANewJourney.jsx

ANewJourney.js

```
/// Modify map - does not work in other levels
for (var x = 0; x < map.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < map.getHeight(); y++) {
        if (map.getObjectTypeAt(x, y) === 'tree') {
            map.placeObject(x, y, 'empty');
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
function getRandomInt() { return 4; }
map.placeObject(42, 8, 'empty');
```

or

```
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-8, 1, 'empty');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-18, 1, 'empty');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-13, 2, 'empty');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-8, 4, 'empty');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-8, 7, 'empty');
map.placeObject(map.getWidth()-16, 6, 'empty');
map.placeObject(10, 20, 'exit');
```

### bonus / AB_2_FrozenCave.jsx

FrozenCave.js

```
/// Modify map - does not work in other levels
for (var i=2; i<41; i++) {
    map.placeObject(i, 7, 'empty');
}
```

### bonus / AB_3_BoulderMadness.jsx

BoulderMadness.js

```
color: 'white',
/////
color: 'yellow',
/////
color: 'red',
```

### bonus / AB_4_BatAttack.jsx

BatAttack.js

```
map.placeObject(6, 23, 'teleporter');
map.placeObject(39, 1, 'teleporter');
var objs = map.getDynamicObjects();
var ts = [];
for (i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    var t = objs[i];
    if (t.getType() == 'teleporter') {
        ts.push(t);
    }
}
ts[0].setTarget(ts[1]);
```

or

```
function wakeAndHunt(obj, type) {}
```

### bonus / AB_5_PathOfDoom.jsx

PathOfDooM.js

```
map.placeObject(45, 12, 'block');
```

### bonus / darkAlley.jsx

darkAlley.jsx

```
map.placeObject(30, 17, 'goldengun');
```

### bonus / ice.jsx

ice.js

```
map.startTimer(function () {
     map.getPlayer().move('up');
}, 25);
```

### bonus / labryinth.jsx

```
if (me.getX() > 43) {
    me.move('up');
}
/////
map.placeObject(1, 10, 'boulder');
for (x = 29; x < 39; x++) {
    map.placeObject(x, 14, 'block');
}
for (var x = 0; x < map.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < map.getHeight(); y++) {
        map.setSquareColor(x, y, '#444')
    }
}
```

### bonus / levelName.jsx

<level name>.js

```
map.defineObject('helper', {
    'symbol': '%',
    'color': '#0f0',
    'impassable': function (player) {
        if (player.getColor() == this.color) {
            return false;
        }
        player.setColor('#0f0');
        return true;
    }
});
map.placeObject(30, 9, 'helper');
```

or

```
map.overrideKey('down', function () {
    var player = map.getPlayer();
    player.setColor('#0f0');
    player.move('down');
});
```

### bonus / noWayOut.jsx

102_noWayOut.js

```
buildWall = function () {};
```

### bonus / pushme.jsx

pushme.js

```
});function moveToward(obj,type){obj.move('down')}var a =({
```

or

```
/// Move the blocks wisely
pushable: true,
```

### bonus / soccer.jsx

soccer.jsx

```
function moveGoalie(goalie) { goalie.move('down'); }
kickedDirection = 'right';
```

or

```
moveGoalie = function () {}
moveEnemyPlayer = function () {}
```

### bonus / threeKeys.jsx

???

### bonus / trapped.jsx

trapped.js

```
moveToward = function () {}
```

Don't push a box against another object.

### bonus / wallsWithEyes.jsx

wallsWithEyes

```
teleport2.setTarget(teleport1);
```

### Non-Documented API

- `map.writeStatus('message');`
- `object.impassable: true, passableFor: ['missile']`
- `object.impassableFor: ['raft']`
- `object.transport: true`  // prevents from collision with object at same position
- `object.pushable: true`
- `object.type: 'block', 'tree', 'teleporter', 'empty'`
- `object.type: 'mine', 'trap'`  // deadly
- `object.type: 'exit', 'player'`
- `object.type: 'computer', 'phone', 'redKey', 'greenKey', 'blueKey', 'yellowKey', 'theAlgorithm'`
- `object.type: 'eye', 'guard'`
- `object.type: 'item', onPickUp: f(), onDrop: f()`
- `object.interval: 200, behavior: f()`